# "-" symbol into rsyslog.conf file

Tags: linux, syslog, symbols

I see into my "rsyslog.conf" a "-" symbol before the path, what is it?

Example:

```
mail.info       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.err        /var/log/mail/err
```

Thank's

Comment: What does your research show?

Comment: Hint: your research should start at [`man rsyslog.conf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html). The answer is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the site: [fedoraproject](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/monitoring-and-automation/Viewing_and_Managing_Log_Files/)

I see:

*Use a dash mark (-) as a prefix of the file path you specified to omit syncing*

```
FILTER -PATH
```